#  installing adhoc distribution but profile gives error 

Tags: iphone, xcode, distribution, provisioning

Profile does not match application bundel identifier.

com..BayerCropSciences this is my application identifier and 
my certificate has

com.celeritas.Cerenia

how to fix this issue and make the certificate work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make the bundle identifier for the app com.celeritas.cerenia or download the right certificate from the provisioning portal

Comment: how to male the right certificate if i dont want to change the name and name the same which is com.celeritas.ByaerCropSciences

Comment: well in xcode go to the info.plist and edit the bundle identifier to what you need it to be and then download and open the profile from the provisioning portal and it should work